# How to position table in list format

Tags: html, django

I am new in Django and in stackoverflow and need your help.

I have a list

```
year=[2020,2019,2018,2017,2016]
grade=[20,90,40,30,69]
category=[fail,distinction,satisfactory,fail,good]
```

I want to have the following format:

```
2020  20   fail
2019  90   distinction
2018  40   satisfactory
2017  30   fail
2016  69   good
```

The format i use is

```
<table>  </table>  botstrap
```

Would be thankful for your help. I am new in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) for this:

```
# view
def some_view(request):
    year=[2020,2019,2018,2017,2016]
    grade=[20,90,40,30,69]
    category=['fail','distinction','satisfactory','fail','good']
    context = { 'results': zip(year, grade, category)}
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)

# html

{% for year, grade, category in results %}
    {{ year }} {{ grade }} {{ category }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: is there any other way without employing zip() ?

Comment: I do not think there is any better way if you are considering combining three lists.